# Speeding up a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-performance

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5
FROM
    MYTABLE
WHERE
    FIELD1 = .... AND
    FIELD2 = .... AND
    FIELD3 = ....
GROUP BY
    FIELD4
;
```

Note that the only thing I changed are the names of the fields and the table. My query does have 5 fields in the `SELECT` statement and 1 table in the `FROM` section. The `WHERE` and the `GROUP BY` sections also looks exactly like that: 3 fields with equals condition.

The fields `FIELD1`, `FIELD2` and `FIELD3` are both PKs and indexes.

**The problem:** The query takes almost 8 seconds to finish (and it returns around 30 rows).

**The question:** Is there any way I can speed up the query, that isn't server related (increasing cache, running the database in a more powerful server, etc...)?

**EDIT:**

Fields declaration:

```
FIELD1: VARCHAR(2)
FIELD2: VARCHAR(3)
FIELD3: VARCHAR(7)
FIELD4: VARCHAR(4)
FIELD5: VARCHAR(5)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Output of `SHOW INDEX`: http://ibin.co/1LSSwvr0CVpX

**EDIT 3:**

Output of `EXPLAIN`:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
table: MYTABLE
type: ALL
possible_keys:
key:
key_len:
ref:
rows: 2081601
Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**EDIT 4:**

Example data:

```
Chicago = 1 (neighborhoods 001, 002, 003) (neighborhood zone 1, 2, 3) (postal code 10, 20, 30)
NY = 2 (neighborhoods 001, 002, 003) (neighborhood zone 1, 2, 3)(postal code 10, 20, 30)
Los Angeles = 3 (neighborhoods 001, 002, 003) (neighborhood zone 1, 2, 3)(postal code 10, 20, 30)
```

Data

```
1    001    1    10
1    002    1    10
1    002    1    20
1    002    2    20
1    003    1    30
2    001    1    10
2    002    1    20
3    001    1    10
3    002    1    10
3    002    2    20
```

What I do:

Search all postal codes that match TOWN == 1 (Chicago) AND Neighborhood == 001 AND ZONE == 1
and then GROUP BY the postal code. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the table?

Comment: One thing you could do to help track issues like this down is to enable the mysql slow query log. https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/slow-query-log/

Comment: Use indexes, try running an EXPLAIN <your query here> query to see how mysql handles it and optimize your indexes from that output.

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen I'm already using indexes. Let me try ```EXPLAIN```

Comment: What value types are the fields that you check in your `WHERE`?

Comment: Hi, the other factor is the where clause. The where clauseis parsed from the end to beginning and therefor you can try to optimize your where clause to achieve better performance.

Comment: Run "update stat *".  It could be the server statistics are outdated and no longer choosing the best path.

Comment: may you share your table structure and output of show index from table1

Comment: @Jite Please see edit for fields declaration

Comment: @ZafarMalik http://ibin.co/1LSSwvr0CVpX

Comment: If `FIELD1` is a PK then why are you doing a GROUP BY on FIELD1?

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen Please see edit for ```EXPLAIN``` output.

Comment: @FuzzyTree FIELD1 is not the only PK. Thus, I group by FIELD1 because I want to group by all the same FIELD1 fields that have different FIELD2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SQL optimization and is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @alexandernst please let me know which is field1, 2 & 3 in show index results you provided...if you share table structure then ie result of show create table mytable; then will be easy to understand your problem

Comment: @ZafarMalik The fields are CPRO, CMUM and CUN. And I'm grouping by CPOS; I just realized the GROUP BY part doesn't group by FIELD1, but by FIELD4, anyways, this shouldn't matter, right? CPOS is PK and index too.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Oh, I just realized that the GROUP BY field actually isn't indexed. Shold I index it?

Comment: First of all recheck why you are making primary key on 6 columns by this you will not get benefit of primary key...any way you need to create a separate combined index on field1,field2,field3 and check your query performance...right now you query is not using index as your table has only single primary key index and this index order does not match with your searching pattern.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Ok, I created another index only with those 3 fields that are in my WHERE. How can I tell MySQL to use that index in my query?

Comment: @alexandernst now explain your query now it should show index and also reduced scanned rows count...please share results.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Ok, so now my query uses ```USE INDEX (my_index_of_fields123)```, ```EXPLAIN```confirms that, but the time it takes is the same.

Comment: @alexandernst: What you explain makes no sense. You say that FIELD1 + FIELD2 + FIELD3 form your primary key. So how can you get back 30 records when having a WHERE clause asking for exactly one FIELD1 + one FIELD2 + one FIELD3? You should get exactly one record! Then you show your index and it's not just field 1 to 3, but all fields! Then there is one field called id, but it's not the primary key! Do you actually know what a primary key is?

Comment: @alexandernst: Does the statement actually do what you want it to do? You group by FIELD4, but don't aggregate any of the other fields, so you get the desired FIELD1, FIELD2, and FIELD3 plus a random FIELD5 per FIELD4. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, I know what a primary key is. And yes, I get exactly the results I want. I filter by FIELDS 1, 2 and 3 and then I group by field 4, which gets me all different fileds "4" that match what I'm looking in field 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Okay. It is just rare to look up a random match (FIELD5 in this case). And I would expect ID to be the table's key. Why else have an ID? Well, back to the Problem: How many records do you get without the GROUP BY?

Comment: @alexandernst share following 2 results: 1st explain results and 2nd show table status from mydb like 'mytable'; results

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Please see edit for more explanations and data.

Comment: @ZafarMalik INDEX: http://ibin.co/1LSrzu9VXujr  STATUS: http://ibin.co/1LSs7i5f6LVj

Comment: @alexandernst I asked explain results but you have provided show index..please shrare explain query results.

Comment: @ZafarMalik oops, sorry. EXPLAIN: http://ibin.co/1LStjvr07jqF

Comment: So for one TOWN + Neighborhood + ZONE + postal code there can still be many entries?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, 1 TOWN + 1 Neighborhood + 1 Neighborhood ZONE can have more than 1 postal code with the same number, because the database contains one row per street, so every street is saved as TOWN + NEIGHBORHOOD + ZONE + PC . I know that is far from optimal, but that is how the DDBB is given to me and I'm not allowed to change it, so I must focus on making it work as good as I can.

Comment: @alexandernst: oops problem is with your searching method just inclosed your values field1='value' like this as these are varchar and you are using with out quotes...

Comment: @ZafarMalik o...m...g... I can't believe that. How could I even miss it? Indeed, now the query runs in about 0.02 secs. If you want, place this in an answer so I can accept it and upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem seems with your searching method just inclosed your values like field1='value' as these are varchar and you are using with out quotes. By this your query will use index and you get performance.

Note: There is no need to use index as mysql do it its own.

Answer (score 1):

With the information now given

1. The table contains streets along with their postal codes, zone, neighbourhood and town.
2. You are looking up postal codes and are not interested in the streets (so you wouldn't select FIELD5 in your example as I understand it now).
3. You can not change the table design, but you can add indexes.

you should have an index on TOWN + NEIGHBORHOOD + ZONE + PC. This contains all information you need and points to all streets associated. The dbms should be clever enough to notice that no table access is needed as all data required is present in the index. That should speed up your query significantly.

Answer (score 0):

1. you mention that you use indexes, make sure an index contains all fields you mention in your select
2. it can be that it returns only 30 rows, but it has to go through many more rows due to

   GROUP BY
       FIELD1

so you might want to "tighten" your query by adding "LIMIT XX", "SELECT DISTINCT FIELD 1" nad such

Comment: I don't see how DISTINCT FIELD1 is any different from GROUP BY FIELD1. ?

Comment: if you have a proper index, they should be the same or in distinct's favour, if your indexing is off, group by might be faster. it depends on the shape of your query and size of data as they are similar in execution yet not identical

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look to implement a partitioning strategy. For big table it's the only way to significantly improve performance.

Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html